# Polymer v1.0 - Data Binding changes not propagating

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, 2-way-object-databinding

Trying my hand at Polymer v1.0, Am currently loading 2 datasets. The first set will set the view and repeat my custom elements. The 2nd set is async loaded, upon loading it will try to match via the routeid if available. On match it will insert itself as an object into the 1st object.

When i do this, the view doesn't get updated, but if i do a console.log and trace it, the data is there.

I discovered if I were to clear the 1st object, use async and set it back later, the view gets updated, but this would cause my display to be blank for a while.
How can i force it to redraw with the updated content?

First one sets the view of items.

```
[ 
        {
            "anchors":[ 
                {"anchorid":1, 
                 "routes":[ 
                     {"name":"route 1", "routeid":1 },
                     {"name":"route 2", "routeid":2 },
                     {"name":"route 3", "routeid":3 }  
                 ] 
                },
                {"anchorid":2, 
                 "routes":[ 
                     {"name":"route 4", "routeid":4 },
                     {"name":"route 5", "routeid":5 },
                     {"name":"route 6", "routeid":6 }  
                 ] 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "anchors":[ 
                {"anchorid":3, 
                 "routes":[ 
                     {"name":"route 7", "routeid":7 },
                     {"name":"route 8", "routeid":8 },
                     {"name":"route 9", "routeid":9 }  
                 ] 
                },
                {"anchorid":4, 
                 "routes":[ 
                     {"name":"route 10", "routeid":10 },
                     {"name":"route 11", "routeid":11 },
                     {"name":"route 12", "routeid":12 }  
                 ] 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

2nd dataset

```
 [
  {"routeid":3, "status":2},
  {"routeid":5, "status":3},
  {"routeid":1, "status":1}
 ]
```

My element codes

```
    <dom-module id="anchor-listdebug">
    <template>
        <h1>Anchor list</h1>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
            <h2>Anchor Group </h2>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.anchors}}" as="anchordata">
                <anchor-item anchor="{{anchordata}}"></anchor-item>

            </template>
        </template>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer ({
            is:"anchor-listdebug",
            ready : function () {
                //data is loaded here via iron-ajax
                this.data = data;
                //data2 is loaded on data response
                this.data2 = data2;

                // emulate 2nd set of data loading, if this.processData is called immediately, content updates fine.
                this.async (this.processData, 1000);
            },
            processData: function () {
                this.data.forEach (function (element) {
                    element.anchors.forEach (function (anchorElement){
                        anchorElement.routes.forEach (function (routeElement){
                            var myID = routeElement.routeid;
                            var data = this.data2.filter(function (record){
                                return record.routeid == myID;
                            });
                            if (data.length >0) {
                                data = data[0];
                                routeElement.data = data;
                            }
                        }); 
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="anchor-item">
    <template>
        <h2>Anchor ID: {{anchor.anchorid}} </h2>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{anchor.routes}}" as="routedata">

            <route-item route="{{routedata}}"></route-item>
        </template>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer ({
            is:"anchor-item",
            properties: {
                anchor:{ type:Object, notify:true}
            }

        });
    </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="route-item">
    <template>
        <h3>Route id: <span>{{route.routeid}}</span></h3>
        <h3>Route name: <span>{{route.name}}</span></h3>
        <h3>Route status: <span>{{route.data.status}}</span></h3>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer ({
            is:"route-item",
            properties: {
                route:{ type:Object, notify:true}
            }

        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: I found a hack of a solution.   
Create a new object to temporary store data.   
Set data = {};   
Do the object manipulation to the temp object;  
Create another async function with a minimum delay of 1  
Then set data = temp object.   
My display view will then get update with the new content.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you use the set API for manipulating your objects ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#path-binding)). Instead of `this.data.anchors = someValue` use `this.set("data.anchors", someValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to use `this.set("data.anchors", someValue)` as was previously stated. You will also need to change your template binding, or the resulting notification will be ignored. Instead of using `anchor="{{anchordata}}"`, you'd either have to use `anchor="{{anchordata.*}}"` to listen to all record changes, or `anchor="{{anchordata.SPECIFIC_KEY}}"` if you want the changes to respond to just one specific key within the data.

Comment: I am not sure where do i do this.  The data i am changing is in a object inside an array inside an array inside another object. Array -> Object -> Array -> Object -> Array -> Object -> Add a new object here

Comment: Do i do the set() function where my "routeElement.data = data;" line is? But what is my path? Will it be "data[index].anchors. routes[2ndindex].newdata" ?

Comment: You should start with a simple template repeat until you get the grasp of it. Consider the following example, for an array property `data`. Which reminds, me you haven't declared your `data` to be a property. Anyway, for that array, if you want to set an item with index 5, you'd do the following:  `this.set("data.5", item)`. From there, you can go deeper. If the item is an object, you can set a specific key of that object using the following: `this.set("data.5.someKey", someValue)` and so on.

Comment: In general, you should definitely read the docs about binding, especially structured data: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#path-binding

Comment: Awesome. Initially when I read the docs, I somehow over looked that. I only read that it didn't support Arrays, and I assumed there's some other method to doing it. Also the other problem i realise was I couldn't use "this.set" in the forEach loop as it's scope was different.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Updated my forEach loops to include the index to use to construct the path to use for the set() function.

```
<script>
        Polymer ({
            is:"anchor-listdebug",
            ready : function () {
                //data is loaded here via iron-ajax
                this.data = data;
                //data2 is loaded on data response
                this.data2 = data2;

                this.async (this.processData, 1000);
                //this.processData();
            },
            processData: function () {
                var scope = this;
                this.data.forEach (function (element, index1) {
                    element.anchors.forEach (function (anchorElement, index2){
                        anchorElement.routes.forEach (function (routeElement, index3){
                            var myID = routeElement.routeid;
                            var data = this.data2.filter(function (record){
                                return record.routeid == myID;
                            });
                            if (data.length >0) {
                                data = data[0];
                                var tpath = "data."+index1+".anchors."+index2+".routes."+index3+".data";
                                scope.set(tpath, data);
                            }
                        }); 
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```